# How to consolidate date and time dimensions to a DateTime?

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I have data something like this:

```
category_id | date (string) | time (string)
    1          2011-08-21       09:16:06    
    2          2012-09-29       10:18:26
```

I now want to consolidate `date` and `time` dimensions to a `DateTime` as timestamp format. How can I do this?

Comment: Sorry, it did not work in the Athena. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `date_parse()`?

```
select date_parse(date || time, '%Y-%m-%d%H:%i:%s')
```